# WCF: Call Service using parameter in URL with &

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

I have my WCF service with URL template like..

```
http://localhost:8448/service/SearchProduct/{productid}/{categoryid}/{search}/{pageSize}
/{currPage}
```

Here, I want to call this service path by using & parameters in the URL, like..

```
http://localhost:8448/service/SearchProduct/?productid=10&categoryid=34&search=newproducts&pageSize=10&currPage=5
```

But when I call service using above path, I got the exception "Endpoint not found."

Could you please tell me How would I call this service by using passing parameter in the URL `with &categoryid=10&currPage=10` ??

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to modify your URI template like that :

```
http://localhost:8448/service/SearchProduct/?productid={productid}&categoryid={categoryid}&search={search}...
```

It should work