# Invoke a Operation Contract through web browser

Tags: wcf, url, browser, uritemplate, webget

Since i am new to WCF and Having configured a WCF service endpoint in IIS at Virtual Directory `Api` ( url goes like **http://localhost/api/taskapi.svc**) i was looking for ways to make request through web browser something like `http://localhost/api/taskapi.svc/GetCompleted` would respond with JSON that lists all completed tasks hence these two posts here gave me some answers

- [Invoking WCF service method through a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802518/invoking-wcf-service-method-through-a-browser)
- [How to consume WCF web service through URL at run time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193124/how-to-consume-wcf-web-service-through-url-at-run-time)
- [WCF: Call Service using parameter in URL with &](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408041/wcf-call-service-using-parameter-in-url-with)

ok hmm so i changed my OperationContract to like below

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetCompleted", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    IList<Task> GetCompleted();
```

but still the url `http://localhost/api/tasksapi.svc/GetCompleted` in browser responds with `400 Bad Request`.

#### Service Contract

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITaskContract
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/task", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    TaskLibrary.Task CreateTask(TaskLibrary.Task myTask);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/task", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    IList<TaskLibrary.Task> GetTasks();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "DELETE", UriTemplate = "/task", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    bool DeleteTask(string taskId);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", UriTemplate = "/task", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    bool UpdateTask(TaskLibrary.Task myTask);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/task/{taskId}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    IList<TaskLibrary.Task> GetById(string taskId);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/task/completed", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    IList<TaskLibrary.Task> GetCompleted();

}
```

#### Service Config

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="TaskApi.ServiceBehavior" name="TaskService.TaskService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="TaskService.ITaskContract">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="TaskApi.ServiceBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

#### Reference Directive

`<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="TaskService.TaskService" %>`

the service is picked from assembly which is output of WCF Service library

#### Url rewrite to hide **svc** extension

```
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Svc Extension remove pattern">
          <match url="^([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z\-\.\/\(\)]+)" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.svc/{R:2}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

- What should i do to make this work?

Comment: can you show your service config? how is your endpoint defined? Casn you show us the .svc file service directive?

Comment: @RichardBlewett Certainly i can, just wait for a few minutes for me to edit the post

Comment: @RichardBlewett Sorry for the delay, I have added configuration information about the service with the question. could you help resolve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK your binding is wsHttpBinding. You need to change it to webHttpBinding (or add another endpoint). Then you need to add an endpointBehavior in the behaviors section as follows

```
   <endpointBehavior>
       <behavior name="rest">
           <webHttp/>
       </behavior>
   </endpointBehavior>
```

This behavior wires in the functionality to map Uris to methods. Then you need to reference this behavior from the webHttpBinding endpoint using the behaviorConfiguration XML attribute

Comment: Seems there is another configuration mistake The message with To `URL/api/taskapi.svc/tasks` cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree.

Comment: two things: I thought you had a URL rewriter in to remove the .svc; you are using tasks as your uri but your contract states GetCompleted - can you give us the new config just in case there is now a typo in it or something

Comment: Updated the source . all i though is from the service contract that when i call `/Tasks` with `GET` request then `GetTasks` method is invoked. Am i right?

Comment: GetTask would be called with /task (no s) according to your contract but I think the error is coming from the fact that something is assuming SOAP - can we see your service config

Comment: I am totally new to wcf by service config do you mean web.config or app.config file? i got app.config in wcf service library project and web.config in wcf service application

Comment: The service library config is ignored - the only config that matters is the web one - in .NET dlls dont have config only apps do - which does beg the point of why a config is created for a lib project but maybe someone form the WCF team should answer that ;-)

Comment: You havent got the endpointBehavior that I showed in my answer in the config file - without this the mapping of Uris to contract operations won't work